# (cons (car L) (cdr L)) is not same as L, when L is not empty?

Tags: scheme, racket

I have seen the following code:

```
#lang r5rs
(define ma-liste-1 (list 2 3 4 5))
(define ma-liste-2 (list 6 7 8 9))

(define (cons! e L)
  (set-cdr! L (cons (car L) (cdr L)))
  (set-car! L e))

(cons! 1 ma-liste-1) 
ma-liste-1 ; (list 1 2 3 4 5)
```

I just do not understand why the following code does not work:

```
#lang r5rs
(define ma-liste-1 (list 2 3 4 5))
(define ma-liste-2 (list 6 7 8 9))

(define (cons! e L)
  (set-cdr! L L)
  (set-car! L e))

(cons! 1 ma-liste-1)
ma-liste-1 ; #0=(mcons 1 #0#)
```

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(set-cdr! L L)
```

produces a `cons` cell whose `cdr` references itself circularly, in ASCII art

```
 .-> ( CAR . CDR )
/            /
\___________/
```

while `(set-cdr! L (cons (car L) (cdr L)))` first reconstructs the `cdr` so that there's no circular reference.

Answer (score 1):

You are forced to make a copy, else as you can see, you end up mutating an existing list, and end up making it a circular list (that notation is used for such shared structures).